# PHP sessions in redis ignores session.cookie_domain configuration

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, setcookie

I have a couple of subdomains that share the same sessions. I used to have a single server, and i had the following the the `php.ini` to allow keeping same cookie for all subdomains:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".mydomain.com"
```

using this configuration makes the server return the following set-cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=aumsloucmjspvs1mbvromqq1b5; path=/; domain=.mydomain.com
```

Now that I have few servers, I wanted to use `Redis` to to share the sessions between all servers. I set up the server and added the following to `php.ini`:

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = tcp://192.1.1.1:6379?auth=noauth
```

The sessions are saved successfully on the server, but the set-cookie returned is incorrect:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=cec074e4d961ff6c800c21b7466c7d5a; path=/
```

So on the next call the client to a different subdomain it doesn't send the cookie he got from the first subdomain.

I'm using PHP 5.3.18, redis 2.2.5, in sessions in `phpinfo()`:

```
Directive               Local Value  Master Value
session.auto_start      Off          Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off          Off
session.bug_compat_warn Off          Off
session.cache_expire    180          180
session.cache_limiter   nocache      nocache
session.cookie_domain   .example.com     .example.com
session.cookie_httponly Off          Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0            0
session.cookie_path     /            /
session.cookie_secure   Off          Off
session.entropy_file    no value     no value
session.entropy_length  0            0
session.gc_divisor      1000         1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  43200        43200
session.gc_probability  1            1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5    5
session.hash_function   0            0
session.name            PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files       files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php/session       /var/lib/php/session
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Any idea how can i force the server to send the proper set-cookie?

Comment: I don't understand how changing your session save path is going to change the domain used for session cookie.  That is odd behavior.  By any chance, have you tried setting the cookie path at runtime using `session_set_cookie_params()` to see if you are able to get different behavior?

Comment: yea, i tried it but it didn't help :(

Comment: What value do you get for `ini_get('session.cookie_domain')` at run time?

Comment: when setting the config in php.ini empty, and using `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', ".mydomain.com");` I get the new value, but the request response still have set-cookie with wrong domain.. to me it looks like a bug in PHP...

Comment: Why don;t you show your related PHP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a tip I got from a friend, I moved the same configurations to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` and for some unknown reason it started working!

If anyone here understands the reason it helped I would love to hear it, and I hope this will help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To set session name as Redis prefix have resolve the problem for me :

```
session_name('PHPREDIS_SESSION');
```